# Javascript if statement failing

Tags: javascript, c#, code-injection

I am not entirely sure why this is happening. What I am trying to do is inject a C# variable into the javascript if statement, but it is not executing how I want it to, and I am not sure why.

I have a list in my C# namespace

C# list:

```
List<string> unitNamesMainChart = new List<string>();
```

On load this list has nothing in it, so I want to make sure I am not accessing the list without anything in it, as that will throw an error so I have an if statement in javascript.

Javascript

```
if(<%=unitNamesMainChart.Count %> >= 1 ){
    a = <%= unitNamesMainChart[0] %>
}else{
    a = ''
}
if(<%=unitNamesMainChart.Count %> >= 2)
        {
            b = <%= unitNamesMainChart[1] %>
            }else{
            ba = ''
        }
 //etc. There are numerous if statements.
```

So ideally, I would like to check if there is anything in the list, if there is, set it to variable `a` in javascript, and if there is nothing in the list then set `a=''`

What is actually happening, is when the code is executed, it crashes at `a = <%= unitNameMainChart[0] %>` because there is nothing in the 0th spot.

Any idea why the code would be executing like this?

Comment: Can you post what the page source looks like after the javascript has been rendered?

Comment: I cannot, because the an error page pops up. Since the javascript code executes on page load, the page fails at the start.

Comment: I just looked, I wasn't aware of that. Although the problem is solved. Thanks

Comment: By way of clarification, this exception is being thrown by the view rendering, so it never actually produces JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
if(<%=unitNamesMainChart.Count %> >= 1 ){
```

is converted to this line in javascript:

```
if(0 >= 1){
```

where 0 can be any number, any probably is actuality zero.

This line:

```
a = <%= unitNamesMainChart[0] %>
```

is converted to:

```
a = --Something--
```

Where `--Something--` is suppose to be the first value of the array.

You are mixing JavaScript and .net code incorrectly.

You are looking for something like this:

```
<%if(unitNamesMainChart.Count >= 1){%>
  a = <%= unitNamesMainChart[0] %>;
<%}
else
{%>
  a = -1; // or something
<%}%>
```

The JavaScript that you will see on the page will be:

```
a = -- Something --
```

The if\else is .net code while the output (`a = -- Something --`) is JavaScript.

Comment: Let me update the question, as I think I should have added more code.

Comment: hmmm Okay, I think your edit makes sense to me. Let me try to adapt this code into mine.

Comment: This did work out for me. I was confusing the javascript if statement and the C# if statement.

Additionally,  why is it that I need the `=` in the line `a = <%= unitNamesMainChart[0] %>;` and I don't need it when encasing the C# if statement?

Comment: `<% code %>` creates a .net code scope where you can execute .net code.
`<%= code %>` creates output from .net code.
Examples:
`<% var a = 7; a++; %>` vs `<%= myStr %>`

Comment: Hmm alright, that makes sense to me then. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that there's a mismatch between what you're checking in C# and what you're checking in JavaScript. As it's currently written, your `if` statement is checked in JavaScript on the browser, but `unitNamesMainChart[0]` gets evaluated by C# no matter how big the list is.

I'd recommend moving all the logic into C# and leave the JavaScript without any `if/else` branch:

```
a = <%=((unitNamesMainChart.Count >= 1) ? unitNamesMainChart[0] : "''")%>;
```

Or, more succinctly:

```
a = <%=unitNamesMainChart.FirstOrDefault() ?? "''"%>;
```

Comment: That doesn't answer the question of why the "If" statement is failing in Javascript....

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing code executed server-side and client-side, it is important to understand where and when everything is executed.

On the server side, we are just generating text, the Javascript constructs have no meaning and the `if` is not evaluated. It's just text. That means `<%= unitNamesMainChart[0] %>` will be executed in all cases, since it is not protected by a server-side test (and of course, it gives you an exception if the list is empty).

You can rewrite your code like this to avoid the problem:

```
<% if (unitNamesMainChart.Count > 0) {%>
   a = '<%= unitNamesMainChart[0] %>'
<% } else {%>
   a = ''
<% } %>
```

This time, the test is executed server-side, and you won't try to get the first element if the list is empty.

Answer (score -2):

The problem is the javascript may be rendering the .Count function as string an not as an integer. Try using the following wrapped around the .Count statement to ensure it's cast a number.

```
parseInt(<%=unitNamesMainChart.Count %>)
```

Comment: That's not what's happening. Look again.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior good job down voting for no reason, ok, so what is happening if you're so sure that not what's happening?

Comment: I apologize if I came across as curt. I'm working on writing the answer in an answer post.

Comment: By way of additional explanation, <%=unitNamesMainChart.Count%> is going to output just an integer (e.g. `42`) which will be interpreted as a number literal in JavaScript (`if(42 >= 1)`), which is just fine. The key is where the OP said " it crashes at `a = <%= unitNameMainChart[0] %>` because there is nothing in the 0th spot". In other words, the C# code is breaking, not the JavaScript.